# Mapbox - Hover over polygons is not working at all. How to get it to work with vector data?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I cannot get hover to work.

Below is my code.  As I move my mouse over the map, the correct polygon ids are displayed in the console.

```
    map.on('mousemove', 'aa_winter_sports_polygons', (e) => { // layer you want to listen on
        if (e.features.length > 0) {
            console.log(e.features.length); // this works and give 1 when defined
            if (hoveredStateId !== null) {
                console.log('hoveredStateId is NOT null and is: '+hoveredStateId); // this works and give an id #
                map.setFeatureState(
                    { 
                        source: 'aa_winter_sports_polygons', 
                        sourceLayer: "aa_winter_sports_polygons_source_layer",
                        id: hoveredStateId
                    },
                    { 
                        hover: false 
                    }
                );              
                console.log('e.features[0].aa_winter_sports_polygin_id: '+JSON.stringify(e.features[0].properties.aa_winter_sports_polygin_id)); // with works and gives a polygon number.
            }
            hoveredStateId = e.features[0].properties.aa_winter_sports_polygin_id;
            map.setFeatureState(
                { 
                    source:     'aa_winter_sports_polygons', 
                    sourceLayer: "aa_winter_sports_polygons_source_layer",
                    id: hoveredStateId
                },
                { 
                    hover: true 
                }
            );
        }
    });
```

Layer was added as follows;

```
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'aa_winter_sports_polygons',
        'type': 'fill', 
        'source': 'aa_winter_sports_polygons', 

        'source-layer': aa_winter_sports_polygons_source_layer, // for vector layers
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': '#93E7FB', 
            'fill-opacity': [
                'case',
                    ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
                        0.5,
                        1
                    ]
        }
    });
```

Again, the light blue polygons display on my map well.  When I move my mouse over the polygons, all the numbers are given in the console.  The aa_winter_polygons_id is an integer.  I tried promoteId : `'aa_winter_sports_polygin_id'` when adding the source but no change.

Answer (score 0):

The `feature-state` is worked with `id`, not worked with `properties`.

I recommend you to get `hoveredStateId` from `id` as the Mapbox example wrote, not from `properties->aa_winter_sports_polygin_id` to check that you get `id` properly.

```
hoveredStateId = e.features[0].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can check on first

1. Make sure the value pass to the `sourceLayer` matches the name of the source layer in `map.addLayer`.
2. Make sure the `hoveredStateId`  defined before you added the event listener.